# Add label to SwiftUI TextField

Tags: swiftui

Is there a way to add a label to a TextField in SwiftUI. I can't find anything in the documentation. I only see a way to add a placeholder.

`TextField("Name", text: $name)`

I'm looking to add a label to match the Picker styling

`Picker(selection: $categoryId, label: Text("Category"))`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by wrapping it in an HStack

```
HStack {
    Text("Name")

    Spacer()

    TextField("", text: $name).multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
}
```

Comment: Consider `.fixedSize()` too for the `TextField`.

Comment: The Spacer() makes no difference here and you wouldn't want TextFields to be trailing as that doesn't match with the standard form.

Answer (score 19):

From iOS 16, the correct way to do this seems to be

```
LabeledContent {
  TextField("Name", text: $name)
} label: {
  Text("Name")
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/labeledcontent

Comment: The documentation suggests it will style elements consistently in the container but I found the TextField will not align with the Picker nor the read-only LabelContent. Using `.multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)` on the TextField seems to align it correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Common idea is simple:

```
HStack {
    Text("Name")
    TextField("", text: $name)
}
```

everything's more is depending on your UI design needs.

Answer (score 2):

This is under documented from Apple's side.

The label is unfortunately only supported on MacOS, if and only if enclosed in a Form element:

```
   Form {
       TextField("Channel", text: $channel)
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best solution, but if you give your Text views a fixed frame width and alignment, it will work. However you probably want to test this out with different accessibility settings.

```
HStack {
  Text("Name").frame(width: 100, alignment: .leading)
  TextField("Name", text: $name)
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to move that `.frame(width: 100, alignment: .leading)` to the end of the HStack?